# docker containers - missing attribute

Tags: docker, terraform

I needed a custom centos image with docker installed. So I built it using centos image and tagged it custom (shown below).

`$ docker image ls`

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
centos              custom              84766562f881        4 hours ago         664MB
centos/systemd      latest              05d3c1e2d0c1        7 weeks ago         202MB
```

I am trying to deploy couple of containers using Terraform on my local machine, each with a unique name that comes from another file. The docker images are on local machine. Here's the TF code.

`$ cat main.tf`

```
provider "docker" {

}
resource "docker_image" "centos" {
  name = "centos:custom"
}
resource "docker_container" "app_swarm" {
  image = "${docker_image.centos.custom}"
  count = "${length(var.docker_cont)}"
  name = "${element(var.docker_cont, count.index)}"
}
```

When I run terraform apply, I get this error which I am not sure how to fix. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
* docker_container.app_swarm: 3 error(s) occurred:
* docker_container.app_swarm[0]: Resource 'docker_image.centos' does not have attribute 'custom' for variable 'docker_image.centos.custom'
* docker_container.app_swarm[1]: Resource 'docker_image.centos' does not have attribute 'custom' for variable 'docker_image.centos.custom'
* docker_container.app_swarm[2]: Resource 'docker_image.centos' does not have attribute 'custom' for variable 'docker_image.centos.custom'
```

Yes, the other file exists with names, its a simple list.

EDIT:

Thanks David, tried your suggestion and amended the code to look like-

```
provider "docker" {

}
resource "docker_image" "centos" {
  name = "centos:custom"
}
resource "docker_container" "app_swarm" {
  image = "${docker_image.centos.latest}"
  count = "${length(var.docker_cont)}"
  name = "${element(var.docker_cont, count.index)}"
}
```

But now I get this error.

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* docker_image.centos: 1 error(s) occurred:
* docker_image.centos: Unable to read Docker image into resource: Unable to pull image centos:custom: error pulling image centos:custom: Error response from daemon: manifest for centos:custom not found
```

I guess I will have to setup a local Docker repository to get this working but I am not sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the specific fields listed in [the `docker_image` resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/image.html) in the `${docker_image.centos...}` interpolation.  In particular, even though you don't use the tag `:latest`, you need a `.latest` property reference:

```
image = "${docker_image.centos.latest}"
```

(If the image actually is one you've built locally, you may also want to specify the [`keep_locally`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/image.html#keep_locally) option on your `docker_image` resource so that `terraform destroy` won't delete it.)

Comment: Thanks David, see my edit above in the original question.